# Angularjs Phonegap Android using Websockets

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, angularjs, websocket

I don't even know how to explain this directly, but I'll try.

**Intro**

I'm building a Phonegap App with angularjs, and I'm trying to stitch up WebSocket messages to update my UI. I used to have services that communicate with the server periodically and change their data accordingly and it was working pretty well. An example:

*Service1.js*:

```
     var applyUpdate = function (
         angular.extend(instance, data);
         if (!$rootScope.$$phase) $rootScope.$apply();
     };

     this.update = function () {
         DataProvider.get('getThermostatSettings', {}, applyUpdate, function(){}, true);
     }
```

So basically I was simply calling the "update" function every 5 seconds, receiving data from the server and updating this service. The controllers would then simply access this service, and everything was working.

**The problem**

The problem now, is that I stitched up a WebSocket Interface written in java, that handles all the websocket implementation for me. I took it from: https://github.com/ziadloo/PhoneGap-Java-WebSocket . It basically registers an Javascript Interface accessible from Javascript to communicate with java.

Everytime I have a change now, I simply push a string from the server via the WebSocket saying that it should update, and then I call the "update" function from the service in my javascript, instead of querying for data periodically, which is just stupid.

The WebSockets are working well. I can see the message coming, I call the update, it fetches everything correctly from the server, the "update" function calls then the "applyUpdate" with the correct values and etc, even the "$rootScope.$apply" gets called.

**But all updated data inside the angular Service is not visible! It seems that all these changes are being run in a different thread!?!?**. I know javascript is single threaded, but it just seems so.

Let me put this in a better way: **I have the impression that as soon as the WebView calls the javascript callback function, I have a different javascript "thread" running, and nothing outside it can be accessed**

**More about it**

I wrote a function that simply outputs a number every **5 seconds**. The websocket updates this number. And my output is the following:

```
N: 1
N: 1
```

Then after the WebSocket pushes the data with a new Number (2), I get TWO prints:

```
N: 1
N: 2

N: 1
N: 2

N: 1
N: 2
```

Anyone has any pointers about this? Anyone tried doing something similar? I'm no angular pro, but it just seems that everything gets messed up as soon as I get a callback from the java interface.

I have already looked at: [Angularjs model changes after websocket data push from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702981/angularjs-model-changes-after-websocket-data-push-from-server) and my code looks very similar. The only problem I think is this callback from Java.

Thank you

**Update** : It's a problem with AngularJS. If I set this variable in a window global variable, everything get's assigned normally. Is it possible that Angular is somehow creating two different $scopes?

**Update[2]**: Just to be a bit more clear: In the browser, everything works as expected. Only when I run it in the emulator that this thing gets messed up.

Comment: Are you serving js application and java api from the same domain?

Comment: The javascript makes some cross-domain requests, but they all work, including the WebSocket. See please my update. It seems that angular is creating two scopes somehow. If I set this variable in a global namespace everything works out.

Comment: Ok then where do you define `instance` and `data` used in `applyUpdate`. `Data` is obviously returned from websocket, and what's `instanse`?

Comment: `var instance = this;` on the very beginning of the Angular Service. That's basically `this`. There values are being set. I've put already a log after this line to check if the values are being set correctly, and they are.

Comment: Just to be a bit more clear: In the browser, everything works as expected. Only when I run it in the emulator that this thing gets messed up.

Comment: Hey guys, I'm new to both phonegap and angularjs, I've [tried](http://briantford.com/blog/angular-phonegap.html) these [tutorials](http://devgirl.org/2013/06/10/quick-start-guide-phonegap-and-angularjs) but none seemed to work (they worked on Xcode/ios but not android).. can anyone point me to a repo that has a complete project of angularjs/phonegap on android? thx!

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely possible for Angular.js to be making two $scopes. Just see the debugging in [this screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-7mhcHXSfM&feature=youtu.be).

It may help to [show all the $scopes on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514147/in-angularjs-how-do-you-find-all-the-scopes-on-a-page).

You should also be aware that [websockets on mobile aren't the best idea](http://lanyrd.com/2012/krtconf/szprz/). Crashes and failures seem to be pretty probable, based on that talk (by a Nodejitsu employee with expertise in websockets).